# The average rate of growth of the least common multiple of the first $n$ positive integers is 1 is equivalent to the prime number theorem

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I encountered the following exercise in the beautiful book *Neverending Fractions* by Borwein, van der Poorten, Shallit, and Zudilin. They refer to the book *The Distribution of Prime Numbers* by A.E. Ingham.(Chapter I, Theorem 3). But I was not able to link Theorem 3 to the Exercise in this book! Perhaps I do not understand what they mean. Anyway, let me state their question.

Prove that the following two statements are equivalent :

1. (*The Prime Number Theorem*) For real $x$, let ${\pi}(x)$ be the number of primes less than or equal to $x$. Then, $${{\lim}_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}}{\frac{\pi{(x)}}{x/{\log}x}}=1.$$
2. Let ${d_n} = {\rm{lcm}}(1,2,\cdots ,n).$ Then, $${{\lim}_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}}{\frac{{\log}({d_n})}{n}}=1.$$
   Not sure how to even approach this!

Answer (score 1):

For each prime $p\le n$, $d_n$ contains the highest power $\alpha_p$of $p$ that is $\le n$. Thus

$$\log d_n=\sum_{p\le n}\log p^{\alpha_p}\le\sum_{p\le n}\log n=\pi(n)\log n\;.$$
This establishes that the limit in $2$. is at most the limit in $1$.

To prove that it’s also at least the limit in $1$., you could try to show that the proportion of primes $\le n$ that are greater than, say, $n\exp\left(-\sqrt{\log n}\right)$, goes to $1$, as does the ratio of their logarithm to $\log n$:

$$\frac{\log\left(n\exp\left(-\sqrt{\log n}\right)\right)}{\log n}=\frac{\log n-\sqrt{\log n}}{\log n}\to_{n\to\infty}1\;.$$

Comment: Should the displayed inequality be $$\log d_n=\sum_{p\le n}\log p^{\alpha_p}\le\sum_{p\le n}\log n=\pi(n)\log n\;?$$ This would imply if we divide both sides of $$\log d_n \leq \pi(n)\log n\;$$ by $n$ and adjusting the denominator on the right hand side we we prove that expression in statement 2 is less than or equal to the epression in statement 1 (the PNT).

Comment: Can you expand on your remark about proving that the limit in 2, is at least the limit in 1.? Thanks!

Comment: @student: Indeed, sorry, those logarithms were missing in the displayed equation.

Comment: No worries! The argument is beautiful.

Comment: @student: About the "at least" part: Consider the primes between $\frac n{10}$ and $n$. These all occur once in $d_n$ for $n\gt10^2$. Also, $\frac{\log(n/10)}{\log n}\to1$ as $n\to\infty$. If the proportion of these primes among the primes $\le n$ would also go to $1$ as $n\to\infty$, we'd be done. It doesn't (it goes to $\frac9{10}$), but we can fix that by instead considering the primes between $\frac nr$ and $n$ and letting $r\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ while keeping $r\lt\sqrt n=\exp\left(\frac12\log n\right)$; that's the point of the choice $r=\exp\left(\sqrt{\log n}\right)$.

Comment: @student: Come to think of it, we don't actually specifically need $r\lt\sqrt n$, since primes occurring multiply in $d_n$ only increases $\log d_n$. So any $r(n)$ such that $\frac{\log r}{\log n}\to0$ and $r\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ would do. But $\frac{\log r}{\log n}\to0$ does imply that eventually $r\lt\sqrt n$.